# Blank Screen When using Echo '<DIV>..</DIV>'

Tags: php, html, html-select, dropdownbox

I am currently trying to enable a select view within the page. However, I have encountered an issue. The page will display a list of items/objects when the following PHP code is used:

```
<?php

echo elgg_view_title($vars['entity']->title);
echo elgg_view('output/longtext', array('value' => $vars['entity']->description));                              
echo elgg_view('output/longtext', array('value' => $vars['entity']->my_options));
echo elgg_view('output/tags', array('tags' => $vars['entity']->tags));
echo elgg_view('output/my_options', array('my_options' => $vars['entity']->my_options));
```

However, the page would be blank when I add in the following code ontop of the above code:

```
echo '<DIV> <html>
    <body>

        <select>
            <option value="A">a</option>
            <option value="B">b</option>
            <option value="C">c</option>
            <option value="D">d</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html> </DIV>'
```

Therefore, the entire code would look something like this:

```
<?php

echo elgg_view_title($vars['entity']->title);
echo elgg_view('output/longtext', array('value' => $vars['entity']->description));                              
echo elgg_view('output/longtext', array('value' => $vars['entity']->my_options));
echo elgg_view('output/tags', array('tags' => $vars['entity']->tags));
echo elgg_view('output/my_options', array('my_options' => $vars['entity']->my_options));

echo '<DIV> <html>
    <body>

        <select>
            <option value="A">a</option>
            <option value="B">b</option>
            <option value="C">c</option>
            <option value="D">d</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html> </DIV>'
```

Can anyone, pls help and point out what's seems to be wrong? Thank you

Comment: OH!! A `<div>` tag before `<HTML>` ?? that is awkward..

Comment: Try replacing `echo '<DIV> <html>
    <body>

        <select>
            <option value="A">a</option>
            <option value="B">b</option>
            <option value="C">c</option>
            <option value="D">d</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html> </DIV>';` with `echo '<div>
        <select>
            <option value="A">a</option>
            <option value="B">b</option>
            <option value="C">c</option>
            <option value="D">d</option>
        </select></div>';`

Comment: try the above solution in my comment @developer

Comment: Learning about the basic structure of HTML code would be most helpful in this case. Otherwise you will be running into troubles like that again soon.

Comment: @Lal so you removed <html> and <body> ??They are not needed?

Comment: yes..they are not needed..also you missed a `;` at the end..

Comment: @Lal arh, that is the syntax error!!Thanks, working now!

Comment: Let's be clear here: they aren't needed *in this context*, since they presumably already exist on the final rendered page.

Comment: You shouldn't be outputting `<html>` and `<body>` tags in `<div>` tags

Comment: That's the third question that shows that you have problem understanding how PHP and web development works. I'd recommend going through few tutorials first.

Comment: @PawełSroka I think that is the reason why I am asking questions that I am unsure of. I think this is a forum where constructive feedback is much appreciated, I didn't get any valuable or positive feedback from comments that you have made. thanks

Comment: @developer There's also something called being "help vampire". One of common cases when someone pastes a lot of code but doesn't care enough to ask the question in a specific way. You created 3 questions for addition of single echoing of the string. That's kinda overkill. Have a constructive read http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.12/admin/getting-help.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `;` at the end of the echo statement.

Replace

```
echo '<DIV> 
<html> 
<body> 
<select> 
<option value="A">a</option> 
<option value="B">b</option> 
<option value="C">c</option> 
<option value="D">d</option> 
</select> 
</body> 
</html> 
</DIV>'
```

with

```
echo '<div> 
<select> 
<option value="A">a</option> 
<option value="B">b</option> 
<option value="C">c</option> 
<option value="D">d</option> 
</select>
</div>';
```

as it is not the correct structure of HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, they're not needed. Remember that a DIV tag is already html, so putting `<html>` tags inside them won't work in this case.

Updated for more info:

```
echo '<div> <select> //your select stuff </select> </div>';
```

Comment: and tags? what is that?

Comment: so it should just be: `echo '<html>
   <select>
      <option value="A">a</option>
      <option value="B">b</option>
      <option value="C">c</option>
      <option value="D">d</option>
   </select>
  
 </html>'`??

Comment: No.  I'll update my post to provide more info.

Comment: Your didn't put the other tags in code format, so were not showing in the post. Remember to proof read and use code formatting for all code ;)

Comment: Answers that recommend to "try doing this" without checking it's the correct solution are not encouraged. While the sentiment is correct, what is written as an explanation would not solve the problem.